# Having trouble configurating SSL on my website

Tags: http, nginx, ssl, https

What do I do to fix my SSL certs on my website? I used

```
# mkdir /etc/nginx/ssl
# cd /etc/nginx/ssl
# openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout server.key -out server.crt -days 1095
# chmod 400 server.key
# chmod 444 server.crt
```

to generate my certs (following archwiki guide)

and I get [image: this]
on my page.

My nginx profile looks like this:

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /path/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/server.key;
...
}
```

I am not sure why I get this warning or what to do to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The warning you're encountering is due to using a self-signed certificate. A self-signed certificate is not verified by a trusted certificate authority, which can lead to browser warnings.

To address this issue, I recommend using a trusted certificate authority to sign your SSL certificate. One popular and free option is Let's Encrypt. Let's Encrypt provides an automated certificate issuance and renewal process, making it easier for website owners to obtain trusted SSL certificates.

You can use the following instructions to set this up

1. Install Certbot:

   - Follow the official Certbot documentation specific to your operating system to install Certbot, the Let's Encrypt client.
2. Obtain and Install SSL Certificate:

   - Open a terminal or shell session and run the following command:

     ```
     sudo certbot certonly --nginx -d www.example.com
     ```

     This command will automatically obtain and install a signed SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt for your domain (replace `www.example.com` with your actual domain).
3. Update Nginx Configuration:

   - Open your Nginx configuration file in a text editor:

     ```
     sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/your_site.conf
     ```
   - Make sure the SSL certificate and key paths in the server block match the ones obtained from Let's Encrypt:

     ```
     server {
         server_name www.example.com;
         listen 443 ssl;
         listen [::]:443 ssl;
         ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
         ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
         ...
     }
     ```
   - Save the file and exit the text editor.
4. Restart Nginx:

   - Restart Nginx to apply the changes:

     ```
     sudo service nginx restart
     ```

After following these steps, your website should have a valid SSL certificate signed by Let's Encrypt, resolving the warning message. It's important to note that Let's Encrypt certificates expire after a specific period, typically 90 days. Certbot will handle the automatic renewal process for you, ensuring your certificates remain up to date.

Remember to adjust the file paths and server names in the instructions according to your specific setup.